# Transferring equations from Excel To C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to convert an excel spreadsheet to a small program made with C#.

The equation I have on excel is:

```
if(S6>=3.55;1;if(S6>2.25;0.8;if(S6>1.61;0.65;0.5)))
```

where `S6` is the cell where the value I check is written.

I tried the following:

```
        if (width>=3.55)    
        {
              double radius = 1.0;

           else if (width>2.25 )
            {
               double radius = 0.8;      
            }
                else if (width>1.6 )
                {
                    double radius = 0.65;        
                }
                   else
                    {
                        double radius = 0.5;
                    }
        }
```

But it doesn't work, so what I'm missing, how should I declare the variable radius which is dependent of the variable width? The message on C# says that I cannot declare the variable "radius" in the current scope, should I declare the variable before the loop? The MSDN help file only use a fixed value with a return statement inside the if statement, this means I cannot have a variable dependency inside the if{} loop?Also, there is any other more effective way to do this kind of conditional logic?

Comment: Tiny reminder: original equation uses 1.61 while you use 1.6

Comment: Your original Excel formula doesn't look like it will compile: all instances of `;` should be changed to `,`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated the question trying to clarify my problem.

Comment: I think you just made the problem more confusing. Does the answer by Robert Harvey and myself not make sense? Also `if` is not a loop structure.

Comment: @Michael It is a ";" instead of a "," because of regional preferences on Windows.

Comment: @vasja Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you for the correction, both answer were clear and both worked. I'm still getting the hang on how to ask questions here, so sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` block does not contain `else`/`else if` statements. You need to close the original `if` statement first. Also, declaring a local variable in each scope and not using it doesn't make any sense. You likely want to declare `radius` outside the scope of any of the if/else blocks

```
double radius;
if (width>=3.55)    
{
   radius = 1.0;
}
else if (width>2.25 )
{
   radius = 0.8;      
}
else if (width>1.6 )
{
    radius = 0.65;        
}
else
{
    radius = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: The indentation doesn't really matter (the white space is not significant), although it's atrocious style.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree; I wasn't trying to comment on the indentation (although I fixed it during my copy-paste).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer, it worked. My  mistake declaring the variable inside the statements, also thanks for the indentation correction.

Comment: @NMA Hopefully you also fixed the unexpected `else if`, but I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Declare `radius` *above the `if` statement.*  Fix your braces.  Align everything properly.

```
double radius = 0;

if (width >= 3.55)    
{
    radius = 1.0;
}
else if (width > 2.25 )
{
    radius = 0.8;      
}
else if (width > 1.6 )
{
    radius = 0.65;        
}
else
{
    radius = 0.5;
}
```

Declaring your `radius` variable inside the `if` statements causes the variable to go out of scope (disappear) when you leave the `if` or `else` statement.